# Performing ArcGIS Network Analyst Routing on one side of street before other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arcgis-10.5

I am having issues with ArcGIS Network Analyst when I am trying to solve some addresses to find the best route, in a walking perspective.

How can I stop the program from jumping from one side of the street to the other?

I want the street to be walked all odd numbers first, and then all even

[image]

Comment: I'm not licensed for Network Analyst so cannot test, and cannot recall having done this to provide details of how it is done from memory.  However, what you are describing sounds like it will use the same principles as garbage truck collections because they pick up from one side of a street at a time.  Searching on "garbage truck routing" may uncover some leads.

Comment: Under our focused Q&A format, be wary of saying "I tried so many things" and not describing any of them in detail.  For focused Q&A it is always best to say what you want to do, describe one thing that you tried in detail, and then describe where you got stuck i.e. I expected to see ... but what I got was ...